# Handlebars template not iterating correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

I am building an app using node.js + handlebars. My server sends two objects to my view: `users` and `companies`. My users load fine, but for some reason my companies will not populate my dropdown list:

```
{{#each users}}
            <tr>
                <td id="id">{{id}}</td>
                <td>{{first_name}}</td>
                <td>{{email}}</td>
                <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="confirm">Confirm</button></td>
                <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="disable">Disable</button></td>
                <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="delete">Delete</button></td>
                <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="view">View</button></td>
                <td>
                    <select id="company" class="form-control">
                        {{#each companies}}
                        <option>{{company_id}}</option> <!-- This will not populate -->
                      {{/each}}
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            {{/each}}
```

Anyone know what might be going on?

As a side note, if I try to render my `companies` outside of the table, it works. For example:

```
{{#each companies}}
    <p>{{company_id}}</p>
  {{/each}}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you describe 'companies' is at the top scope.  Use `{{#each ../companies}}.`